# How to prevent microphone from picking up movement?

Tags: audio, microphone

I have a MEMS microphone mounted to a PCB in an enclosure. The purpose of the microphone is to detect sound, like someone talking. When I just barely touch the enclosure or move it around, the microphone detects it.

How can you de-couple the microphone from the circuit board and enclosure so it doesn't detect physical movement of the enclosure? How do other devices like smartphones deal with this?

Comment: start with a high pass filter.

Comment: consider the balanced open rear to cancel near field noise with rubber baskets between case and sensor

Comment: How do you know this type of noise is low frequency?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Consider wher the vibration is coupling from, the ambient noise (-ve) pressure vs the acoustic port (+) pressure and use suitable vibration decoupling rubber gasket seals. The MEMs mic acts as a differential pressure sensor. So the coupling needs to be reduced to balance emanated source pressure via input acoustic port.

Comment: What is ambient noise pressure and what is acoustic port pressure? Does ambient noise pressure refer to any outside sounds reaching the microphone or are you talking about ambient noise pressure within the enclosure? Is there a type of putty that can go over the mic to dampen the vibration? I'm not sure how to create a gasket if it's not already custom made.

Comment: ambient ,I mean unwanted  local vibrations. How did you mount it?  Acoustic port is a small rectangular air port. Did you get this on yours?  see black on my diagram?

Comment: I'm not sure what the acoustic port is exactly...the way the MEMS mic is mounted on my board is underneath the PCB with a hole in the PCB above the hole in the MEMS mic for sound to go through. Maybe the hole is the "air port" you're talking about? This is the mic datasheet (INMP401): https://www.invensense.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/INMP401.pdf

Comment: if your board is rigidly mounted to the case. that is your problem.. read AN-1003

Comment: There's no room for a gasket to put between the PCB and enclosure. Is there some adhesive that can be put on PCB edges to insulate?

Comment: a soft gasket is crucial for isolation not a semi-rigid adhesive